# Changing the label on links

Tags: link

I'm adding content to a site that has been set up in Craft. However, it's been set up so that in one section, any link created has the label "How this works". It's a bit unwieldy as it means I can't use the actual information I want to send people to as the link for example: 
"Spend less money" as the link rather than body text that says "Spend less money" with a link underneath that says "How this works".

Is there any way I can change this behaviour without getting the site designer to change it in template files?

Comment: Did the original developer add that text as editable in the Dashboard? If not it was probably hard coded and you'll need access to the template files.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependant on how the fields and templates are set up.

You don't say how you are creating the link. Craft makes no assumptions as to how you are going to be entering content. It's entirely down to the developer to set up the fields and templates according to your needs.

Do you have a text field specifically for entering the link? If there is no accompanying field to add a title then it's most likely you will need to add one and then modify the template to output that field in the title attribute of the link.

If you are adding a link within a Rich Text field then you should be able to edit it from within there. Though if this were the case I don't know why you would have a default value being used.

Either way, it should be a very minor task for a developer to fix.